# Kubernetes Connectivity

Tags: kubernetes, connectivity, amazon-eks

I have a POD running which had a Java Application running. This Java Application talks to a MySql which is on-prem. The MySql accepts connections from 192.* ip's
I  have the pod running on EKS worker nodes with Ip - 192.*. I am able to telnet Mysql from the worker nodes. When the pod starts, the Java application tries to connect to the Mysql with the POD  Ip  (which is some random 172.* ip) and fails with MySQL connection error. 
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute a shell inside the pod and connect to the MySQL server from there.

```
kubectl exec -it -n <namespace-name> <pod-name> -c <container-name> -- COMMAND [args...]
```

E.g.:

```
kubectl exec -it -n default mypod -c container1 -- bash
```

Then check the MySQL connectivity:

```
#/> mysql --host mysql.dns.name.or.ip --port 3306 --user root --password --verbose
```

Or start another pod with usual tools and check MySQL port connectivity:

```
$ kubectl run busybox --rm -it --image busybox --restart=Never

#/> ping mysql.dns.name.or.ip
#/> telnet mysql.dns.name.or.ip 3306
```

You should see some connection-related information that helps you to resolve your issue.

I can guess you just need to add a route to your cluster pods network on your MySQL host or its default network router.